# How can I switch the linked table for a foreign key field using a flag when defining a model in DRF

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I wanna create 3 models in models.py.
Like this:

```
class Female(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField()

class Male(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=4)
    name = models.CharField()

class People(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    s_id = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

I want to connect People to one of both Female and Male according to People.sex.

For example:
In class People

- if sex = F, then

  - s_id = models.ForeignKey(Female)
- if sex = M, then

  - s_id = models.ForeignKey(Male)

limit: Female and Male's id length are not same. 3 models must not add varible, after migrate need to be seen in database. I want to insert data to People table like this:

```
INSERT INTO people (id,sex,s_id) VALUE (1,'F','f00001')
INSERT INTO people (id,sex,s_id) VALUE (2,'F','f00002')
INSERT INTO people (id,sex,s_id) VALUE (3,'M','M001')
INSERT INTO people (id,sex,s_id) VALUE (4,'M','M001')
```

I research lots of document and QA, try some like GenericForeignKey, Choice. But useless.
Please help me, How can I fix the model to acheive this needs?
thanks a lot~

Comment: It looks quite bizarre modeling. Probably a more sensical way would be defining a `Person` model with a `sex` field, and the `Student` just referring to `Person`, it can then take the `sex` field from the related `Person` if necessary.

Comment: Right, thanks for remind!